# How do I deliver a nested JSON array for content reference with export view display?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-8

I created a product content type with content reference to article(one product to many articles). Then I added field `"Content: ID" "Content: Title"` and `"(field_article: Content) Content: Title"` to a new REST export View. `"(field_article: Content) Content: Title"` come from the relationship "Content referenced from field_article" I added in advance.

I have been working on drupal8.

The output is:

```
[
{
    "nid":"3",
    "title":"Product1 title",
    "article_title":"Article1 title"
},
{
    "nid":"3",
    "title":"Product1 title",
    "article_title":"Article2 title"
}
]
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
[
{
    "nid":"3",[enter image description here][1]
    "title":"Product1 title",
    "articles":
        [
            {
                "title":"Article1 title"
            },
            {
                "title":"Article2 title"
            }
        ]           
   }]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the same question on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201789/how-do-i-deliver-a-nested-json-array-for-content-reference-with-export-view-disp).

I've created a very simple module [REST Export Nested](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/imclean/2869279) to support nested JSON using [Views Field Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

After installing "REST Export Nested":

1. Install and enable [Views Field
   Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)
2. Create view display of referenced content (Articles in your case) of type "REST export" or "REST export nested"
3. Add a relationship to the parent entity and contextual filter of parent entity ID
4. Create a view display of the parent entity of type "REST export
   nested"
5. Add required fields (e.g. "nid", "title")
6. Add a field of type "Views field" (e.g. "articles"), configure with
   the correct View and display and pass "nid" as the contextual filter

The module doesn't depend on Views Field View and may work with other fields which produce a JSON string.